# Finding origin of rejected mails (550 5.5.1)

Tags: postfix

Recently all the mails that my clients are sending from one of my servers started to go straight to the SPAM folder. After a quick search using http://multirbl.valli.org it came clear that it's because my server was in a brown list.

It turns out that Sender Score has lowered my server to a mere 50/100 because apparently someone in that server is sending tons of emails that are getting rejected (as per Sender Score's explanation: https://senderscore.org/faq/ , section `Unknown Users`).

How can I find out who (which email account) is sending all those emails that are getting rejected?